# Allowed Currencies only show DKK in backoffice

Tags: magento2, currency

I need to know why is my Magento 2 installation only showing DKK as the currencies? And I also need to know how to add another currency in allowed currencies list such as USD and Euro
[image: Text]
any help would be greatly appreciated.
thanks

Comment: Go to `advanced->system->currency->installed currencies` and see how many currencies are installed there.

Comment: yes that solved it. thanks though